# Solving quadratic inequality $x^2 > 0$

Tags: inequality, roots, quadratics

This particular inequality has me puzzled:
$$ x^2 > 0 $$

Graphically it is simple to solve, as you can see the curve only touches $0$ but stretches off in both negative and positive directions as shown here:

[image: This is it]

However I cannot express in a calculation how I can come up with $$x > 0 \lor x < 0. $$

For instance if you attempt to solve the inequality by finding the square root on either side, you end up with:
$$ x > \pm\sqrt{0} $$
Since zero is neither positive or negative, this doesn't really make much sense to me. Or is there a different way to interpret this?

Thanks

Comment: Maybe induction is what that's gonna work, @turpachull

Comment: You can think of it as $|x|>0$.

Comment: Consider three cases, $x< 0$, $x=0$ and $x>0$ and in each of them solve the inequality separately.

Comment: Take $x=-5.$ You will have $x^2>0$ but surely not $x>0.$

Comment: I think you can solve this the same way as all inequalities. First solve the equation with the equation sign, in this case
$$
x^2 = 0
$$
The next step is to consider the real line and separate it at the points where the roots are. Indeed you will only separate it at $x=0$. The three cases are then: when $x<0$, the equation is true. At $x=0$, the equation is not true. At $x>0$, the equation is again true. Therefore, the solution is $x<0~\text{or}~x>0$, or equivalently, $x\neq 0$.

Comment: A different kind of inequality is $\quad x^2>0 \implies  x\ne 0$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Caution,

$$a^2>b$$ does not imply $$a>\pm\sqrt b.$$

But $$\pm a>\sqrt b$$ is correct. (With a somewhat sloppy notation.)

---

More rigorously

$$a^2>b\\\iff (a-\sqrt b)(a+\sqrt b)>0\\\iff (a>\sqrt b\land a>-\sqrt b)\lor (a<\sqrt b\land a<-\sqrt b)\\\iff a>\sqrt b\lor a<-\sqrt b.$$

Comment: It was a little hard to follow but I think I see how it works. This is what I was looking for, thanks. Kudos to the other contributors too.

Answer (score 3):

We have that

- for $x=0 \implies x^2=0$
- for $x \neq 0 \implies x^2>0$

and the proof is complete by [exhaustion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_by_exhaustion).

Following your idea, using that $\sqrt{x^2}= |x|$, we can take the square root both sides to obtain

$$x^2>0 \iff \sqrt{x^2}>\sqrt 0 \iff |x|>0$$

which is always true for $x\neq 0$.

Comment: I think I am missing some important properties of absolute values here. So if  $\sqrt{x^2} = |x|$, how does this show that x could be a negative value and thus $x < 0$ can also be true?

Comment: @turpachull We have that $x^2>0$ is equivalent to $|x|>0$ which is always true for $x\neq 0$.

Comment: @turpachull Using the aquare root for the proof, the key point is that $\sqrt {x^2}=|x|$.

Answer (score 1):

When you applied the square root on each side you shouldn't have "cancelled out" the square root with the square power.

I think you are used to do something like this: $x^2=a$ then $x=\pm\sqrt a$, which is fine, but doesn't work with inequalities. Instead you should be thinking it more like this: if $x^2=a$ then $|x|=+\sqrt a$, which also works with inequalities.

For example: if $x^2=4$ usually we say straightforward $x=\pm2$, but you could do a middle step, which is $|x|=2$, and then think that the absolute value just gets rid of the minus sign, so your solutions can be $x=\pm2$.

This is the way you should do the inequality: if $x^2>0$ then $|x|>0$, so you can have either $x>0$ or $x<0$, since the absolute value will get rid of the minus sign.

Answer (score 1):

$$x^2=0\iff x=0.$$ Hence

$$x^2>0\iff x\ne0.$$

Answer (score 0):

As a general rule, I have discovered the following:

$$\mathrm{For\:}u^n\:>\:0\mathrm{,\:if\:}n\:\mathrm{is\:even}\mathrm{\:then\:}u\:<\:0\quad \mathrm{or}\quad \:u\:>\:0$$

Courtesy of Symbolab. https://www.symbolab.com/solver/inequalities-calculator/x%5E%7B2%7D%3E0